# Get 1 if statments are true

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to get some id-s from a join on multiple conditions.
Example
After join etc.

```
A B
x 1
x 2
x 3
y 1
y 2
y 3
y 5
z 1
z 5
```

so i want those id-s ( A) where for example B is 1 and also 5

> so the result y,z

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using two `EXISTS` may look cleaner :

```
SELECT DISTINCT A
FROM Table1 t1
WHERE EXISTS(SELECT A FROM Table1 WHERE A = t1.A and B = 1)
  AND EXISTS(SELECT A FROM Table1 WHERE A = t1.A and B = 5)
```

Comment: yes I think i use this, cause i'll need more conditons and in and likes. Thanks both of you

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by a WHERE and a GROUP + HAVING, the `HAVING` will ensure that 2 conditions are met.

```
SELECT T1.A
FROM Table1 AS T1
JOIN Table2 AS T2
  ON T2.ID = T1.ID
WHERE T2.B IN(1,5)
GROUP BY T1.A
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2
```

Or if there is a possibility of B having more than one row for 1 or 5 for the same A, you could do this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT T1.A
FROM Table1 AS T1
JOIN Table2 AS T2
  ON T2.ID = T1.ID
 AND T2.B = 1  
JOIN Table2 AS T3
  ON T3.ID = T1.ID
 AND T3.B = 5
```

Comment: Thanks, but I missed one important detail. That maybe more than one condition you because the table is not integers its codewords and one of the codeworks must conatian and some of the others like
First condioitn contains **code like 'XY%'** and also conatin one of this so **code in ( 'ab','cd',bx') or/and like 'gg%'**
sorry for poor description.

Answer (score 1):

```
select A from Table group by A
having max(decode(B,1,0)) + max(decode(B,5,0)) = 0
```

[fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/7a2ee/1)

Comment: A little explanation/context would be helpful for posterity.

Comment: Works nicely for the original post and data. In the OP's comment to another answer he mentions that the conditions can be more complex. But replacing decode with case to make complex conditions possible will make this work fine ;-)

Answer (score 1):

If the conditions are "distinct" in the sense that a given row can only satisfy exactly *one* of the conditions, then something like this can be used:

```
select a
  from table1
 group by a
having count(
   case
      when b = 1 then 1
      when b = 5 then 1
   end
) = 2
 order by a
```

Set up each condition in the case structure and test if the count is equal to the number of conditions.

Alternatively a method similar to the one by Egor Skriptunoff:

```
select a
  from table1
 group by a
having max(case when b=1 then 1 end)=1
   and max(case when b=5 then 1 end)=1
 order by a
```

A max() on each condition.

Both methods do *not* require self-joins.